# FTP on Wso2 ESB

Tags: proxy, ftp, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have a .Net web application that is front-ending the ESB in order to **create Proxies programmatically**.

I am trying to push a xml proxy into the ESB path: `repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/` via FTP but it seems not to work.

I was trying this connection: `ftp://admin:admin@localhost:9443/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/`

There is any other way to upload my XML in the ESB? many thanks

**EDIT**: I know that one answer could be "yes, you can do that by using admin services", but that didn't work for me due to lack of documentation regarding adding proxies via admin services. So I am looking at alternatives like FTP, because I know that placing the xml directly in the Repo folder will work, the problem is accessing the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a proper way to add a proxy to the ESB, possibly using ws-admin services, but that wasn't really straightforward: problem with repositories, libraries etc...

I ended up with a quick a dirty solution: secure java ftp to the server (with jsch )in the proper folder of the proxies.

Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to use FTP to upload a file to a path. This doesn't involve invoking WSO2 ESB, does it?

Based on above understanding, it seems your port specified in [FTP address](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/ftpurl.html) is incorrect. I think you should use the port of the FTP server you are running in your machine. Unless you haven't edit its config, it should be 21. After this change, you need to provide absolute path instead of relative path /repository/...

Think about it as just another FTP upload. ESB automatically deploy any file that comes to /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/ regardless of how it came there.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

1. You could create your proxy within the Web Interface of WSO2 (use a Web Browser):
   `localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp`
2. Or add the proxy by just copying the file

`mv myProxy.xml MY_WSO2/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/myProxy.xml`

An FTP connection to localhost:9443 will not work. Otherwise explain why you need to use FTP?